# IOS User to start in textView area when application launches

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, textview

In my first view I have a textView area. As of now the user would have to click/touch the area to start typing in it.

I want the cursor to be in the area when view load, so you can start typing directly, can this be done?

I also would like the keyboard animation (which then would happen directly) to move slower, can this also be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `becomeFirstResponder` of your `textArea` in `viewDidAppear` method.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [yourTextArea becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

`becomeFirstResponder` from `viewDidLoad` not work properly.

If you need to implement slow animation you can use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
{
     [yourTextArea becomeFirstResponder];
}];
```

Change the duration according to your need.

---

The fully implemented code will look like:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^
   {
      [yourTextArea becomeFirstResponder];
   }];
}
```